# Classes and Subclasses discerning

Tags: python, list, class, subclass

How were I to check if something is a subclass or a class. Say for example:

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self,run,fast):
        """run is a list of speeds or something. But it can be from dogs or cats. Fast is a single number"""
        self.run=run
        self.fast=fast

class Dog(Class):
    def __init_(self,run, fast):
        Cat.__init__(self,run,fast)
        self.jumper=[]

    def update(self)
        for number in self.fast:
            if number is CATTYPE:
                self.jumper.append(number)
            if number is DOGTYPE:
                self.jumper.append(number)
```

Basically I am trying to, where there is all caps, find a way to make the the statement for fast find it it is a cat type or not, then append to jumper. I know it is a silly example but I was wondering about how to approach this when one is a subclass of another.

Comment: I'm confused- is `number` a class, an instance of a class, or a number?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> issubclass
<built-in function issubclass>
>>> class Foo: pass

>>> class Bar(Foo): pass

>>> issubclass(Foo, Bar)
False
>>> issubclass(Bar, Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(Bar(), Foo)
True
```

use `issubclass(B, C)` to check whether B is a subclass of C.

use `isinstance(c, C)` to check whether c is an instance of C or an instance of a subclass of C.

for your problem:

```
if isinstance(animal_instance, Dog): 
    #instance of Dog

if isinstance(animal_instance, Cat):
    #instance of Cat
```

but it seems, from your ambiguous source, like you're trying to build some kind of dog-racing program that keeps track of 'jumping records' and picks 'fast jumpers'. It makes us wonder what you want to do with checking classes of instances.

Comment: "use issubclass(B, C) to check whether **B** is a subclass of **C**", and your example also show this.